# Bi-directional relationship schemas in sanity

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sanity

I'm working on a project where I have two types of schemas in Sanity: 'Member' and 'Project Group.' Each 'Member' schema references a 'Project Group,' and vice versa. What I'm looking for is a bi-directional connection between the two schemas, such that if I update the 'Project Group' of a 'Member,' the 'Project Group' should automatically update its list of members. Similarly, if I update the list of members in a 'Project Group,' those 'Member' schemas should automatically have their 'Project Group' updated.

To achieve this, I have tried to set up an Express server to listen for Sanity webhook events. Whenever there is a change in a 'Member' or 'Project Group' document, the webhook triggers and sends the data to my server. I then use the Sanity client to fetch the updated document based on its _id and manually update the corresponding reference fields in the 'Member' or 'Project Group' schema.
Does this seem like a good approach, or do you have any other recommendations?